# BigQuery FIRST_VALUE() - Return nulls first while still dictating a sort?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

With the following data structure as an example:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-10-18 |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 |
| 1 | 2019-09-01 |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |

I want to be able to partition the data, add a new column with the highest date but with nulls first. i.e

| id | date | first_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-10-18 | null |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 | null |
| 1 | 2019-09-01 | null |
| 1 | null | null |
| 1 | null | null |

In Postgresql this is as simple as:

```
SELECT *, first_value(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id order by date desc nulls first)
```

However, attempting this in BigQuery throws the following error:

```
NULLS FIRST not supported with descending sort order in RANGE clauses of analytic functions.
```

What can I implement to achieve the equivalent result in BQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the WINDOW size with
`ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`

so the final solution became:

```
SELECT *,first_value(date) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `first_value()` (although you could make it work).  Just use `max()`:

```
SELECT *, max(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id order by date)
```

In your logic, if you don't want `NULL`s, then either:

- Use `NULLS LAST` so the `NULL` values are not first.
- Use `IGNORE NULLS` so non-NULL values are given preference.

EDIT:

Oh, you want to do exactly the opposite:

```
first_value(date) over (partition by id
                        order by (date is null) desc, date desc
                       )
```

Comment: Yes that would work if I didn't care about the nulls. But here I want to prioritize nulls if they exist.

Comment: @someKinder . . . That's weird ;). I added another answer.  You can put the `NULL` check in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Aahh ok! That might work! Will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach to avoid extra `ROWS BETWEEN ...`

```
FIRST_VALUE(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY -UNIX_DATE(date) NULLS FIRST)
```

in case if your `data` column is not of date type but rather a string data type - you should add DATE() within UNIX_DATE() as `-UNIX_DATE(DATE(date))`